# Как лучше всего реализовать включение классов из модулей?

Tags: php

Есть папка с самостоятельными модулями, примерно как в wordpress.

autoload уже не использовать т.к. как оно может узнать о пути к классу по его имени? Писать менеджер модулей типо

```
ModuleManager::inc('имя модуля', 'имя класса');
```

Выглядит не очень красиво, сканить все папки модулей чтоб найти классы тоже так себе решение (разве что кэшировать, но все равно кажется, что есть решение лучше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо нарисовать структуру вашего проекта, что и где лежит. И потом строго следовать этим правилам.

Одним из самых главных и правильных правил тут будет использовать для классов пространства имен, совпадающих с реальными путями.

Например, класс лежит в `class/modules/db/Connect.php`, тогда задаем класс так:

```
namespace modules\db;
class Connect{}
```

И тогда можете использовать что-то подобное:

```
const BASE_CLASS_PATH = '/path/to/base/class/directory';
spl_autoload_register(
    function ($class) {
        $class = '/class/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $class).'.php';
        if (is_file(__DIR__.$class)) {
            include_once $class;
        } elseif (is_file(BASE_CLASS_PATH.$class)) {
            include_once $class;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: стоит добавить `spl_autoload_register() позволяет задать несколько реализаций метода автозагрузки описаний классов и интерфейсов. Она создает очередь из функций автозагрузки в порядке их определения в скрипте, тогда как встроенная функция __autoload() может иметь только одну реализацию. ` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 0):

Используй [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) , он покрывает 100% потребностей

Ты сможешь использовать как `psr-0` так и `psr-4`
Твоя задача включить в головной файл `autoload.php`
и расписать конфиг в `composer.json`

psr-0:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Monolog\\": "src/",
            "Vendor\\Namespace\\": "src/",
            "Vendor_Namespace_": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "config",
            "core",
            "modules"
       ],
       "files": [
           "src/MyLibrary/functions.php"
       ]
    }
```

psr-4

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Monolog\\": "src/",
            "Vendor\\Namespace\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```